# How can I fix this error in C using valgrind: invalid write of size 8

Tags: c, memory, malloc, valgrind

After compiling my code, I've got some issues regarding the memory. After doing ./valgrind on my Linux terminal, I've got the following error for this function:

> invalid write of size 8 at read_lines_from_file.

Here is my function `read_lines_from_file`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int lines_count = 0;
char** read_lines_from_file(FILE* file) {
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char** lines = NULL;// ça renvoie NULL si le fichier est vide
    char  line[100];
    while (fgets(line, 100, file)) {// nous faisons l'hypothèse qu'une ligne ne dépasse pas 100 caractères
        line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';// on enlève le \n
        lines = realloc(lines, (lines_count + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        lines[lines_count] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
        strcpy(lines[lines_count], line);
        lines_count++;
    }
    return lines;
}
```

I don't understand where it comes from and how I can correct that to remove this error.

Comment: Note that meanwhile, the incorrect tag has been removed for you (see [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75386142/revisions)).

Comment: What is `lines_count`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: @pmacfarlane lines_count is a global variabl counting the number of line and has a value of 0 at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Instead of `memcpy` + `strcpy` you could just use `strdup`,

Comment: I don't see any valgrind errors. Which line reports the error? And what file are you feeding it? Please add a sample that reproduces the problem. Is your hypothesis about lines being 100 chars or less true?

Comment: Please edit the question with the full callstack(s) from memcheck. If you built your executable with debug information could you also show which line memcheck points to?

Answer (score 2):

Code has at least these problems:

Unclear if any solve "invalid write of size 1 at split".

**Caller lacks info as to how many lines were read**

`read_lines_from_file`, on the 2nd call is not reset to 0 and so conveys to the caller the wrong number of lines.

**Hacker exploit**

`line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';` is UB where the first character read is a *null character*.

Also, input does not certainly include a `'\n'`.

```
 // Better as
line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
```

**Lack of error checking**

Code does not check for allocation errors.

**Lines of 100+ characters are not well handled**